# DataTables: Add class to table cells, but not table headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the following code to initialize jQuery DataTables:

```
var oTable = $('#qpidvulh_to-do_list').dataTable( {
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "item",
            "className": "editable"
        }
    ]
} )
```

The issue with this code is that it adds the `editable` class to the `th` of each column, even though I only want it added to the `td` of each column.

How can I get the code to only add the `editable` class to the cells of each column and not their headers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to mainguy and markpsmith for posting their answers. I'll throw my own solution into the mix, but I'd still like to see what everyone thinks the best performing solution would be:

`$('#qpidvulh_to-do_list thead th').removeClass('editable');`

Answer (score 2):

Use this to add the class to the cell, 100% working solution, make sure the you give the correct target number while adding the class, here **createdCell** function adds class to the targeted cell,

```
var oTable  = $('#<?php echo $module; ?>').DataTable({
                  columnDefs: [{"orderable": true, "targets": 1,
                        'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                           $(td).addClass('myclass');
                           // $(td).parent('tr').attr('data-id', rowData[0]); // adds the data attribute to the parent this cell row
                        }
                  }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but the suggested solution didn't really work for me because I am applying different types of inputs (number, text) selectively to cells in multiple tables. I have an onclick event for the cell to convert it into an editable box. I changed where it is called from

```js
table.on('click', '.edit-text', function() {
    // yadda yadda;
}
```

to

```js
table.on('click', 'td.edit-text', function() {
    // yadda yadda;
}
```

In this way the function ignores the 'th' cells with that class.

EDIT:
A second way I have found is to use the [createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) option in the columns definition:

```js
columns: [
    {
        data: 'property_name',
        createdCell: cell => $(cell).addClass('some-class')
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use jquery?

```
$("td").addClass('editable');
```

Look [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cUXJPywGJVyFzWCtmfjK?p=preview)

**Update**: On second thought: It would be better to put this jquery snippet in the `draw event` of dataTables so it works too when pagination changes and the table is redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback) for this:

```
var oTable = $('#qpidvulh_to-do_list').dataTable( {
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "item"
        }
    ],
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $(nRow).children().each(function (index, td) {
            $(this).addClass('editable');
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"aoColumns":[null,{sClass:'editable'},null,null,{ "sClass": 'my_class other_class' }]
```

Comment: This unfortunately adds the classes to both the cells and the headers.

Answer (score 0):

In my table I put the editable in the draw callback like this:

```
$('#table td.editable-class').editable();
```

and in the column defs I gave the editable cells a class. Here's an example:

```
var table = $('#blocks').dataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: ...
  },
  columns: [
    { data: "column_data",    "name": "column1",   visible: false },
    { data: "editable_column", class: "editable another-class" }
   ],
  "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {

    $('#table td.editable').editable();
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be using CSS.

Just set the CSS class selector to affect the 'td' and not the 'th'.

Try this code:

```
td.editable {
    color: red; /*Or some other attribute*/
}
```

Important: With this solution the 'th' element will still have the 'editable' class set, but it wont be affected by the CSS styling.

If you still need to remove the class on the 'th' element try this:

```
$('#qpidvulh_to-do_list th').removeClass('editable');
```

/*** ADDITIONAL INFO ***/

If you need more info about CSS selectors, try this page:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp